# Let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ have eigenvalues $λ_1, \ldots , λ_k$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ have eigenvalues $λ_1, \ldots , λ_k$. Prove that $\operatorname{ker}(A − λiI) = \operatorname{ker}((A − λiI)^2)$ for each $i = 1,\ldots, k$ if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

I have seen a similar question (for the rank). But how do I proceed to prove the only if direction using the Jordan normal form? Also, I would appreciate the proof for the if direction too. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For the "if" direction, can you prove it if $A$ is diagonal? For the "only if" direction, think about the case where $A$ is a Jordan matrix, and think about what the kernels look like.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: all you need is to do it for a Jordan block.

Comment: Please share more details on this

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=SJS^{-1}$ be the Jordan decomposition of $A$. Because $A$ and $J$ are similar, $\ker((A-tI)^k)=\ker((J-tI)^k)$ for any $t$ and $k$. (Can you show this?) This further shows they have the same eigenvalues. So, without loss of generality, we can instead prove the following:

> Let $A$ be a [Jordan matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix). Then $\ker(A-\lambda_i I) = \ker((A-\lambda_i I)^2)$ for all $i$ if and only if $A$ is **diagonal**.

---

Let $A$ be diagonal. Then the diagonal elements of $A$ are $\lambda_i$ (possibly with repetitions). $A-\lambda_i I$ will be diagonal with some zeros on the diagonal. There is a simple characterization of the kernel (e.g., it has a basis consisting of [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) vectors). The square $(A-\lambda_i I)^2$ also has some zeros on the diagonal. How do they compare with the zeros on the diagonal of $A-\lambda_i I$? What does that tell you about the kernels?

---

Suppose $A$ is a non-diagonal Jordan matrix. Then there exists some Jordan block of size $> 1$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Then in $A - \lambda_i I$ the block has zeros on the diagonal, and $1$s on the off-diagonal, e.g.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Think about what this says about the kernel of $A-\lambda_i I$.

The square $(A-\lambda_i I)^2$ is also block diagonal, and the block of interest is the square of the above matrix that had zeros on the diagonal. Try squaring some examples of such Jordan blocks to see if you can understand how it will look, and think about what the kernel is. You'll find that it is strictly larger than the kernel of the original Jordan block. Thus, $\ker(A-\lambda_i I) \subsetneq \ker((A-\lambda_i I)^2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so helpful.